# How to hide this window in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, window

I have this window appear not on purpose and I would like to remove it, if anyone can help me please

[Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ft8vs.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Those are the *Breadcrumbs*. There's a toggle for them in the toolbar--the first of the two that are "on" in the image.